# How to enable MongoDB C++ driver autoreconnect feature?

Tags: c++, oop, mongodb

I am following examples from http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=133415. If I try to set autoReconnect to true using  `c.autoReconnect= true;` I get error message -  `‘const bool mongo::DBClientConnection::autoReconnect’ is protected|` which is true as per [API documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_connection.html)

so, how do I set autoReconnect to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.   mConn = new mongo::DBClientConnection(true,NULL,NULL );